# Probability that a randomly generated bit string of length 10 begins with a 1 or ends with a 00, given 0 and 1 are equally likely

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So, I know that the general formula to find the probability of independent Bernoulli events is:

$C(n,k)p^kq^{n-k}$

But there are a few questions I have about the application of this theorem to this problem. First off, even though we have 10 indices, we are only concerned with 3 of the options. So I don't know how this formula would apply. Also, I am not sure how to account for the or in this scenario. Is it just that the bit beginning with a 1 is just going to be $\frac{1}{2}$ and the one for the 00 a the end is just going to be $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to use the Binomial Distribution here. As you noticed in your question,
$$P(\text{begins with 1})=\frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$P(\text{ends with 00})=\frac{1}{4}$$
Then use the fact that
$$P(A\space\text{or}\space B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\space\text{and}\space B)$$
for any two events $A,B$. If you let $A=\text{begins with 1}$ and $B=\text{ends with 00}$, you can calculate $P(A\space\text{or}\space B)$, the value you seek, by first calculating $P(A\space\text{and}\space B)$ (which should be a piece of cake, since $A$ and $B$ are independent events).

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate it. That last line was the one I was really missing :)

Comment: @JerseyFonseca No problem! If it helped, don't forget to $\checkmark$ and $\uparrow$! :D